# Determine angle of a straight line in 3D space

Tags: vb.net, math, line

I have a straight line in space with an start and end point (x,y,z) and I am attempting to get the angle between this vector and the plane defined by `z=0`. I am using VB.NET

Here is a picture of the line in my 3d environment (the line I'm intersted in  is circled in red) :

[image]

It is set to an angle of 70 degrees right now.

Comment: I think one usually uses the Cross Product to find the angle between two vectors. Or is it Dot Product? I bet the Mathematics SE guys will know for sure ;-)

Comment: Isn't the answer to *this* question the first part of **[this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463415/angle-between-two-3d-lines)** question?

Comment: I'm trying to get the code to solve this problem (perhaps utilizing the Math. feature of .NET) and at the same time, this is only 1 line in a 3D environment, not two @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't remember anything from my maths classes, but in 3D space, wouldn't you need to measure the angle relative to some other line?  Otherwise, wouldn't the apparent angle vary based on the observation point?  (Right now, I am sticking out my index finger and rotating my hand, and watching the angle change).

Comment: @Cimbali Basically, the line I circled is standing at a 70 degree angle. I want to get that value based on the two points I have (startpoint and endpoint). I am assuming the second object needed is the z=0 plane, so yes that is what I am looking for (if the result is correct) Thanks for your comment Cimbali

Comment: @joe you would have to have a second line albeit a virtual one... where the start point would be the start point of your first line and its end point would be an increment on x and y but not on z. (me thinks....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [2 rays to define an angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle).

If you want the angle between a vector and a plane, it is defined for any vector in that plane. However, there is only one minimal value for that, which is the angle between a vector and its projection onto said plane.

Therefore, that minimal value is the one we take when we speak of the angle between a vector and a plane.

This value is also π/2 - the angle between your vector and the the vector that is normal to the plane.You can read more about it all [on this site](http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/distance/line_plane.html).

With `v` your vector (thus `v.x = end.x - start.x` and idem for `y` and `z`), `n` the normal to the plane and `a` the angle you are looking for, we know from the definition of a scalar product that:

```
<v,n> = ||v|| * ||n|| * cos(π/2 - a)
```

We know `cos(π/2 - a) = sin(a)`, and the normal to the `z=0` plane is simply the vector `n = (0, 0, 1)`. Thus both the scalar product, `v.x * n.x + v.y * n.y + v.z * n.z`, and the norm of n, `||n|| = 1`, can be simplified a lot. We get the following expression:

```
sin(a) = v.z / ||v||
```

Thus finally, the formula by taking the reciprocical of the sine and expliciting the norm of `v`:

```
a = Asin(v.z / sqrt( v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y + v.z*v.z ))
```

According to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.asin.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) the `Asin` function exists in your System.Math class. It does, however, return the value in radians:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Double
>   An angle, θ, measured in radians, such that -π/2 ≤ θ ≤ π/2
>   -or-
>   NaN if d < -1 or d > 1 or d equals NaN.

Luckily [the same System.Math class contains the value of π](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that you can do the conversion:

```
a *= 180 / Math.PI
```